# Why fields and properties are called locations in C#

Tags: c#, oop, postsharp

Can someone please explain me why fields and properties are called locations in C#. I am taken aback as I have not come across all these years. I am reading [this](http://www.agile-code.com/blog/aop-method-interception-in-postsharp-with-onmethodboundaryaspect/) and after doing a bit of further research, I found its indeed the case. So my question is, **is this specific to post sharp or its applicable to OOPs in general?**

Comment: In CLR/C# terms, you can refer to fields and properties as *members* (of some type, usually). I guess "locations" only come to play in the realm of Aspect-Oriented Programming.

Comment: Yes, members is known, location is an AOP jargon you mean?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with AOP but I think it's safe to assume it's a PostSharp term

Comment: After reading the title of your question, I wondered who else uses the term location for fields and properties other than post sharp. After reading the description of your question I came to realize that they are the only ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term `location` is used in PostSharp and in the CLI specification. A location is anything that can contain a value. A location has three semantics: read, write and get address. From a CLI point of view, possible locations are fields, local variables, parameters and array elements. PostSharp's `LocationInterceptionAspect` can be applied to fields and properties, which both have read and write semantics.